# Remove wasted commit in our remote feature-branch

Tags: git

I have this tree

```
* commit origin/master
| * commit origin/my-feature-branch
| * commit 
| * commit 
| * commit 
|/  
| * commit origin/other-feature-branch
|/
```

I want to keep `origin/master`, but I want to squash `origin/my-feature-branch` and make it clean. My "strategy" is:

```bash
git checkout my-feature-branch
git rebase -i HEAD~4
# ... leave first pick line and change all others in squash
# ... change commit messages into one
git push origin :my-feature-branch
git push origin my-feature-branch
```

My new tree now is clean.

```
* commit origin/master
| * commit origin/my-feature-branch
|/  
| * commit origin/other-feature-branch
|/
```

Is the correct way?

Comment: This modifies shared commits, which is almost always a bad idea with Git. There are many articles online and many answers on SO explaining why this is discouraged.

Comment: @Chris true, but there are some cases where users actually want to do this, sometimes even when the branch is shared (small dev teams can organize more efficiently to synchronize with rewritten work).

Comment: @Cupcake Agreed. But it's important to understand why doing so is discouraged in order to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically got the right idea, though instead of deleting the remote branch before pushing to it, you can just force push directly to it with

```
git push origin my-feature-branch -f
```

The only reason why you would want to delete the remote branch first is if force pushing is disabled on the remote, so deleting it first is a way to sort of "cheat" and get around that restriction...though if that restriction is there, someone must not want you to force push, so make sure rewriting the branch is something that is actually OK with your team.

**Obligatory warning about pushing rewritten commits to public branches**: if you're branch is shared with other developers, force pushing rewritten commits will force those other developers to resynchronize their work with the new commits, since they'll all have copies of the old ones. This can be a difficult process, depending on the Git skills of your team, so make sure that your team is actually OK with you doing this.